# Folded display of help files?

Tags: help-system

I often find navigation of :help files to be cumbersome. Given that they are mostly structured information, is there an existing way of using this structure for initially folded display?

E.g. after installing a new plugin, I'd like to browse the :help [plugin] by looking at the folded TOC. In a perfect world, after opening help I can see all of the top level help topics and I can descend into any one using zo/zO/similar.

Do you know of a plugin that provides syntax folding for help files, or is there some other easy way to get this working?

Comment: There is already a TOC at the top of every help file.

Comment: That's great, but I want it folded, and folded by default. That's the point of my question.

Comment: Using tags and jumps accomplishes the same thing, in the current help format.

Comment: @VanLaser: Hm, I'm new to tags. How would that look? The folding part specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the folding. Use something like this in your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType vim,help setlocal keywordprg=:help
```

... and then you can hit `K` every time your mouse is on a help keyword/tag, to jump directly to that help topic. To jump back, you can use `Ctrl-o`. This also works for the right part of each line from the TOC (hence its usefulness), and it's more powerful than folding - you can jump between files, and back to were you started.